# How to write xpath without ng-model property for Angular JS application

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am new to Angular JS automation. Have very good experience with Java and selenium but beginner on Angular. I found on internet that Protractor is good choice to automate Angular JS application.

I look at some examples of code where I found `ng-model` property as locator or to identify element uniquely.

In my case I don't see ng-model property so how can I write xpath to interact with particular element.

[image]

Here for example I need to fetch text of Average Price. i.e `USD 0.01153`

I wrote xpath like : `//div[contains(text(),'info-text')]` But getting multiple matches here and that seems not rigid xpath. So is there any other way to write xpath for Angular js elements to identify it uniquely?

Comment: i see (key,item) can't you use `key` by assigning to some attr ? key should be unique .

Comment: @supercool - Can you give example please?

Comment: my above comment is more for a developer so if he includes that it will be useful to identify every element uniquely in above context but i might be less helpful in selenium terms . `div[contains(text(),'USD')] ` does it return div which has USD ? not sure if u can use jquery closest etc to track it based on the label text `average price `

Comment: Yes that xpath returns values with USD but there are many matching elements so that seems not rigid.

Comment: yup just as expected , can you try something like this `div[contains(text(),'average price')]` will fetch you div , later use that div as base & find closest (using jquery) which having class `info-text` it should work but i prefer to ask developer to make changes so each elem is identified in unique way.

Comment: Yes but this is 3rd party website and developers not in my control :(

Comment: yup then try the other way it's cumbersome but i'm sure it will work . as i see all the elements in page are in similar fashion try witting out some generic function which take class & div element returns you the closest div with req'd class to it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below XPath to identify required node:

```
//md-tab-content[contains(@class, "md-active")]//div[normalize-space()="Average price"]/following-sibling::div
```